# Can PyTest addoption be made global variables across all files?

Tags: python, testing, pytest, conftest

I am trying to make user input from pytest addoption to be accessible through all files

I have a `conftest.py` file with code

```
import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    try:
        parser.addoption('--user', action='store', default='', help='Login Email for the API tests')
        parser.addoption('--pwd', action='store', default='', help='Login Password for the API tests')
    except ValueError:
        pass

@pytest.fixture
def get_user(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--user")

@pytest.fixture
def get_pwd(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--pwd")
```

I tried importing `from conftest import get_user, get_pwd` in other files, but it only imports as a function object and not as the value inputed by user.

It is because it is not just the test functions that have to use these values, but there are some more functions in the code that require these values and those functions are not able to identify the fixture values.

I want `get_user` an `get_pwd` to be globally accessible through all files in the directory.
How can I do that?

Comment: Do you need those accessible without running pytest?

Comment: yes, I did
The solution posted below for using pytest_configure worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define hook `pytest_configure()` and store those parameters as globals there.

```py
# your conftest.py

# you should be able to import that
username: str = None

def pytest_configure(config):
   global username
   username = config.getoption('--user')
```

[pytest_configure](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html) (you probably have to search for it)

Better solution would be to add the fixture name to your test function as a parameter, like that:

```py
from conftest import get_user

def test_username(get_user):
    assert get_user == "my_username"
```

[pytest fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#fixtures)

Answer (score 0):

> I want get_user an get_pwd to be globally accessible through all files in the directory. How can I do that?

Why? You've declared them as fixtures, so your test functions can just take `get_user` as parameter and pytest will link the two e.g.

```
def test_a_thing(get_user):
    ...
```

will receive the contents of the `--user` option. I'd suggest renaming the feature to just `user` as well incidentally. And making these "session" fixtures, as they have a constant value across the entire session and no state to teardown.

Also the try/except in `pytest_addoption` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: It is because it is not just the test functions that have to use these values, but there are some more functions in the code that require these values and those functions are not able to identify the fixture values.

Comment: You may want to take a look at *mocks* for this (specifically the patching functions of `unittest.mock`, and possibly the `pytest-mock` extension), intrusively updating the SUT with test values directly sounds like a bad idea. Alternatively, depending on the SUT's design, you can have a fixture simply configuring the SUT if one such entry point exists.